# RxJava for User Registration

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to  register users through a mobile app and store the user data on the cloud.Can I use RxJava at the backend to process the user registration requests ? Or there is no need to really use Rxjava in user registration process ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use RxJava at the backend to process the user registration
>   requests ?

Yes you can.

> Or there is no need to really use Rxjava in user registration process
>   ?

There is no right or wrong answer to this question. Is completely up to you.

Here is a link to a [article on the Netflix tech blog](http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/01/optimizing-netflix-api.html) about RxJava use in their API.

Comment: I am very new to Rxjava so I am trying to identify the functions which should really use Rx and have an observer.for example in my mobile app I am searching for some person in a list of contacts.As I start typing in the serach box , the Observer which will be subscribed should search the contact ( based on the conditions )and send back details right ?.In a typical user registration such scenario  may not exist and users can fill the details and send the request and will be synchronously notified of the successful registration ? Am I correct in identifying the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't particularly gain a lot by using an event sequence for the authentication use case. However, if you are using reactive streams for the rest of your architecture then there is no reason why you couldn't have an authentication object act as an observer for login requests.

Unless you are using reactive extensions for the rest of the architecture then I wouldn't bother personally. What framework are you using? If it has authentication support already available, then go with that if it meets your needs.

Comment: We will be mostly developing it on Android and IBM Bleumix Mobile data to store objects on the cloud.Our application will do general registeration (for an example as a Student I want to register myself to a Educational mobile app)  but at a time we can expect many people doing registrations and we would receive the multiple requests and confirm successful registrations